# How can I use regular expressions to insert commas into large integers?

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have a text document with a lot of large integers, e.g. 123456789. I want to automatically insert commas into these to make them more readable: 123,456,789. However, my document also contains decimals, and these should remain untouched. Is there a regular expressions that will insert these? An answer on a similar question suggested `(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))`, but this also detects decimal numbers. What's more, I am unable to insert the commas using either Notepad++ or Overleaf. What should I replace this regex with?

Comment: So you don't want to insert commas into 53521.35?

Comment: On second though, yes, but not in the decimal part. However, the decimal values are not big enough to warrant commas.

Comment: How many digits can the decimal parts have?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? What regex flavour?

Comment: I use either Notepad++ or Overleaf, whatever works :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe,

```
(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d|\.))
```

or

```
(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\.|\d))
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/wAi543/1)

or

```
\d+\.\d*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\.|\d))
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/jvMTNK/1)

might be close to what you're trying to write, which you can simply replace it with a comma.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4eacow/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/4eacow/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, this also puts commas at the left endpoint, like ```,345```, or ```34.,345```. Do you know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to touch the decimals you could use [(*SKIP)(*FAIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to match a dot and 1+ digits to consume the characters that should not be part of the match.

(Tested on Notepad++ 7.7.1)

```
\.\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

In the replacement use a comma `,`

In parts

- `\.\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Match a dot literally and 1+ digits (match to be left untouched)
- `|` Or
- `\B` [Anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) that matches where `\b` does not match
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is

  - `(?:\d{3})+` Repeat 1+ times matching 3 digits
  - `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not a digit
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX3rnJ/1)